# Ajax function not being called asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically,I am trying to make a like-dislike functionality for my website.Everything is going on smoothly except that when someone clicks the like button, the value increases by 1 but does not outline the like button synchronously(at the same time).I have to reload the page before  I see the button outlined.But I want it done synchronously.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.laravel-like').on('click','i',function(){

    if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
   return false;

   //alert($(this).attr("data-item-id"));
   //alert($(this).attr('data-vote'));

  var item_id = $(this).attr('data-item-id');
  var vote = $(this).attr('data-vote');

  $.ajax({
       method: "get",
       url: "/laravellikecomment/like/vote",
       data: {item_id: item_id, vote: vote},
       dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function(msg){
      if(msg.flag == 1){
        if(msg.vote == 1){
          $('#'+item_id+'-like').removeClass('outline');
          $('#'+item_id+'-dislike').addClass('outline');
        }
        else if(msg.vote == -1){
          $('#'+item_id+'-dislike').removeClass('outline');
          $('#'+item_id+'-like').addClass('outline');
        }
        else if(msg.vote == 0){
          $('#'+item_id+'-like').addClass('outline');
          $('#'+item_id+'-dislike').addClass('outline');
        }
      $('#'+item_id+'-total-like').text(msg.totalLike == null ? 0 : msg.totalLike);
      $('#'+item_id+'-total-dislike').text(msg.totalDislike == null ? 0 : msg.totalDislike);
      }
    })
    .fail(function(msg){
      alert(msg);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `msg.flag` and `msg.vote` on the response?

Comment: @Taplar 1 or -1

Comment: I'm not asking what it can be.  I'm asking in your use case where the page does not update the classes, what are they?

Comment: @Taplar I dunno

Comment: Then throw a couple console.log statements in there and find out.  This is simple debugging you should have already done.

Comment: @Taplar its 1 and the comments `id` respectively

Comment: The flag is 1, and the vote is the comments id?

Comment: @Taplar Lets move to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192917/discussion-between-taplar-and-titox-d-boss).

Comment: Through chat it appears that the issue is related to the endpoint returning incorrect response data.  So, for the time being, this does not appear to be an issue with the ajax call.

Comment: @Taplar Thanks....